# Why are the "minutes of a meeting" called so?

Tags: collocation, appropriate

The points discussed in a meeting once written are termed as "minutes" rather than "points".

What is the rationale?

Comment: Minutes: *written record of proceedings at a meeting of a corporation, society, etc., made by its secretary or other recording officer," c. 1710, plural of minute "summary or draft of a document or letter," which is is attested from mid-15c. Perhaps from Latin minuta scriptura "rough notes," literally "small writing" (see minute (adj.)), on the notion of "a rough copy in small writing."* (Etymonline).

Comment: This could be an answer.